# Create django webapp + REST API endpoints

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to create a website with a mobile application. I worked with web apps and REST apis separately but with this project I have to combine both.

My question is how do I have to combined this two sides of the projects.

Suposse I have a `User` model which has `Task`s. Currently I have those models in an app called, for example, `myRESTapp`. But now, I want to be able to edit the tasks and take advantage of Django forms, but I'm not to do another application called `webapp` and implement forms based on models that are in`myRESTapi`. I think it would not be a good practice considering the modularity of applications.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can have multiple apps in one Django project. I usually have one main app that contains the main models and additional apps build on it.

Also, if you want to use apps in different projects, just make them [reusable](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/intro/reusable-apps/) and put them into separate repositories (which you could add as requirements and install with pip).

As for a REST API, check out the great [Django Rest Framework](http://www.django-rest-framework.org). It provides full CRUD functionality and in combination with crispy forms you can even add/modify data with a simple web UI.

An example of how I structured one of my projects:

```
base                            # basic application
├── __init__.py
├── admin
│   ├── __init__.py
├── ├── filters.py              # custom filters for the Django Admin
│   └── models.py               # enhancements for the Django Admin
├── apps.py
├── db_router.py                # database router to distinguish between default and legacy DB
├── migrations                  # DB migrations (default & legacy)
├── models
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── default.py              # default models
│   └── legacy.py               # legacy models
├── services
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── service1.py
│   ├── service2.py
├── tests.py
manage.py
my_api_app
├── __init__.py
├── apps.py
├── serializers.py              # DRF Serializers
├── services.py                 # specific services for this app
├── tests.py
├── urls.py                     # API URLs
├── views.py                    # DRF ViewSets
my_web_app
├── __init__.py
├── apps.py
├── services.py                 # specific services for this app
├── static
├── ├── css
├── ├── img
├── ├── js
├── templates
├── tests.py
├── urls.py                     # website URLs
├── views.py                    # web views
projectname
├── __init__.py
├── settings
├── ├── __init__.py
│   ├── base.py                 # base settings for all environments
│   ├── dev.py                  # local dev settings (DEBUG, etc)
│   ├── prod.py                 # production settings (default)
│   └── test.py                 # test settings (sqlite DBs for testing)
├── urls.py                     # urlpatterns (API, website & admin) 
├── wsgi.py
requirements
├── base.txt                    # requirements for all environments
├── dev.txt                     # local dev requirements
├── optional.txt                # optional requirements for HTML doc creation
├── prod.txt                    # production requirements
└── test.txt                    # test env requirements
requirements.txt                # default requirements (prod)
scripts
├── post-merge.sh               # githook for deployment on server
├── doc.sh                      # create the code doc
├── coverage.sh                 # create the code doc
```

So I have my base app, that contains the models and everything that's used in both of the other apps and an app for the API and one for the website.

I come from PHP and Symfony, where I really fell in love with the idea of reusable services. That's how I keep logic out of my views and keep closer to an actual MVC (which is something Django isn't)

Comment: I used DRF and Django separately. What I want now is to join that under a project (for example, that from the smartphone `/ users / me` is used to obtain user data but can also be done from a web page). When I just made a webapp, I used the `{{form}}` tags to automatically render the forms on the page. I do not think it's nice to combine the REST part with the web part within the same app, but separating them into, say, `core`,` api` and `webapp` would generate a dependency between them. Any suggestions?

Comment: @nikolat328 Agree, mixing the applications is not a good idea. Splitting them into core, api and webapp is. I updated my answer and included a sample project structure that I like to use for similar projects.